# How to properly handle interruptions of GKSession?

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, gamekit, gksession

My online radio app is playing background music. When the user listens to music and exits the app (enters background) to look elsewhere, I tear down the GKSession. It's P2P mode. When user returns to app, I reconnect GKSession.

Is this the right thing? And what to do if a phone call arrives or other interruption occurs? Also kill GKSession and recreate?

```
NSNotificationCenter *defaultCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    // Register for notifications when the application leaves the background state
    // on its way to becoming the active application.
    [defaultCenter addObserver:self 
                      selector:@selector(setupSession) 
                          name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                        object:nil];

    // Register for notifications when when the application enters the background.
    [defaultCenter addObserver:self 
                      selector:@selector(teardownSession) 
                          name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification 
                        object:nil];
```

Comment: That is what I normally do, but I'm not sure if it is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right. All threads are suspended when your app is in background mode, including `GKSession`'s.

`GKSession` still works when your app is in 'Inactive' mode (e.g. when it's interrupted by a phone call, etc.). Inactive means that the app is still running in the foreground but it’s not receiving events.